# Docker-compose container ports not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running a container that's initiated by docker-container like so:

```
  puppetboard:
    build: ./images/puppetboard
    image: puppet/puppetboard
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    links:
      - puppetdb:puppetdb
```

It successfully builds and when I run `docker ps` I can see:

```
0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp
```

I can even go into the container using `docker exec` and use `curl localhost:5000` which returns an html page.

I double check that host machine can see port 5000 on 127.0.0.2 *(docker network)* with `nmap 127.0.0.2` and the port is available: `5000/tcp  open  upnp`.

Yet when I go to `127.0.0.2:5000` in my browser on the host machine I get website not available. How can I debug this network issue?

Result of `curl 127.0.0.2:5000` & `curl 127.0.0.1:5000` is: `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

Comment: is it a typo? Try 127.0.0.1:5000 (localhost:5000)  instead of 127.0.0.2:5000

Comment: try curl you localhost, 127.0.0.1:5000

Comment: @papey updated question with `curl` result

Comment: @user2915097 I use `127.0.0.1` when inside the container as it is localhost. When I'm on host machine I use `127.0.0.2` as this is the default bridge network with Docker.

Comment: With the mapping you describe inside your docker-compose, try 127.0.0.1 on your **host**

Comment: @papey I'm getting the same result for `127.0.0.1` & `127.0.0.2`.

Comment: is your application configured to listen on 0.0.0.0 inside your container ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144263/discussion-between-philip-kirkbride-and-papey).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we discuss it in this [room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144263/discussion-between-philip-kirkbride-and-papey), you have to ensure that the containerized application listen on all interfaces inside the container. In the puppet board case, config looks like :

```
DEV_LISTEN_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
```

0.0.0.0 is used to say "all interfaces"

Answer (score 9):

127.0.0.x is a loopback address. For publishing ports in the container to the host, you need to listen on all interfaces in the container. So you'll need to make sure your app inside the container is configured to listen on 0.0.0.0:5000 (this is different from the option publishing the port in the docker compose file).